# Populate event table

Tags: php, mysql

I have problem with making event table in php, i don't know even how to start, so it would be great if someone help me with this.

I have table users and cars, now i need to make table event that will follow which user is entered new car in database. 
Can someone help me with making this table that will automatically populate with user_id and car_id that this entered(before user can enter data he must login, so i know which user is entering data, but i don't know how to take his id and car_id which he entered and put in other table(event_table))?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can store user id in PHP session when user loged in.
so when user make any update or insert in car. you can fetch user id from session and insert in event table.